# Installing pyPdf library module in kali linux to work on Pdf files

Tags: python, pypdf

How to install pyPdf module in my kali linux ?
I tried with $sudo apt-get install python-pyPdf
getting the error as

E:unable to locate the package python-pyPdf

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a Python package using Linux native package management system. It won't work. I believe you have Python and pip installed in Kali. Try,

```
pip install PyPdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Kali 2020v4 to solve that issue:

Run

```
sudo bash 
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```

First, check if you have pip3 previously installed

```
pip3
```

If the output is command not found then:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
```

After having it installed or if you have a pip3 previously installed, run the following command.

```
pip3 install PyPDF3
```